# Looking for math history books that I'm not sure exist

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, math-history

I've browsed many math history books, but I've never read too deep into any single one. I always find myself reading the about the same facts and same people over and over -- the set of topics doesn't seem to reflect the richness of mathematical history.

I want to learn how the techniques and topics in math have changed over time, and what role and applications math played in various societies. I find knowing the historical development of more modern techniques really helpful for understanding math from school. As well, I like learning about the different ways different societies think of mathematical concepts.

These are many broad ideas, so I guess I am interested in any historical material (books, websites, etc) that doesn't follow the pervasive pattern I see -- where the exposition is crowded with random biographical details and uncritical praise of mostly upper-class men, with little attention to the broad trends, and women and non-european mathematics barely mentioned.

PS for context I am almost finished an undergraduate degree and have that level of math understanding. I especially like algebra and topology.

Comment: [History of Science and Mathematics SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) may be a better place for this question.

Comment: Would [this book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Crest_of_the_Peacock) be somewhat along the lines of what you are envisioning?

Comment: Looks interesting! The plagiarism accusations on wikipedia don't bode well but may be worth a look. And thanks @Blue I will post there as well.